# How to skip rows while importing ExcelSheet with variable sheetname?

Tags: excel, import, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have to import ExcelSheets with variable Sheetnames via SSIS. Sheetname is determined by scripttask and passed via User::Variable to ExcelSource. The problem is that data/headline always starts at row 11.

How is it possible to pass something like "$A10:AB50" (required data selection) to the sheetname delivered in User::Variable?

I´ve already tried to pass the required data-selection-string (e.g. "$A10:AB50") to OpenRowsetVariable, ExcelConnectionManager, ConnectionString... without success. I also tried skipping/splitting first 10 rows via conditional split, but couldn`t find any approach to this.

A test with a second ConnectionManager getting data from a defined file and that has data access via sql-query (e.q. "select f1,f2... from [sheetname$a1:ab50]") works great indeed.

This is how scripttask determines sheetname:

```
ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FILEPATH + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
                OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

                cnn.Open();
                DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string sheetname = "";

                foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
                {
                    // sheetname only
                    if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$") && !drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("Print_Area"))
                    {
                        sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                        // return sheetname
                        //MessageBox.Show(sheetname);
                        Dts.Variables["User::rSheetName"].Value = sheetname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Simply added the decided data selection to the sheet-return-variable in scripttask:

```
if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$") && !drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("Print_"))
                    {
                        SheetName = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                        // concat datazone to sheetname
                        DataZone = "A10:AB50";
                        SnameValue = SheetName + DataZone;
                        SnameValue = SnameValue.Replace(@"'", "");

                        // return combined sheetname
                        MessageBox.Show(SnameValue);
                        Dts.Variables["User::rSheetName"].Value = SnameValue;

                        cnn.Close();

                    }
```

It was way to easy... thanks for thinking about it anyway ;-)